# Deepwater with Tensorflow a fatal error java

Tags: r, tensorflow, gpu, h2o

I have an error executing the following code R:

```
hsc = h2o.init(ip="127.0.0.1",port=54321,nthreads=-1,max_mem_size="8G")

model_tf <- h2o.deepwater(
  x = col_start:col_end,
  y = col_class,
  backend = "tensorflow",
  training_frame = train)
```

Error from console h2o:

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> SIGILL (0x4) at pc=0x00007f49f117892d, pid=4616, tid=0x00007f4a7d88a700
>
> JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_144-b01) (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
> Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.144-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
>
> Problematic frame:
> C  [libtensorflow_jni.so00358a4a-1301-4222-a4f6-273b7a1baf4c+0x211992d]

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this on an Ubuntu 16.04 machine with an Nvidia GPU and all the requirements met from this page https://github.com/h2oai/deepwater ?

The reason I'm asking is that this is the error you get when you try to run the GPU version on a machine that does not have a GPU.

Deepwater won't work unless the requirements are met. A simple way to do this is to use one of the docker images

https://github.com/h2oai/deepwater#pre-release-docker-image